# LOD in three.js (Merging meshes)

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, level-of-detail

I'm looking for a method, where I can use the LOD Object of three.js in a performant way (http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_lod.html).

My idea is to implement a LOD method, which is like this one in chapter 2.1 (http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=364375).

There are 3 levels:

- a 3D model near the viewer
- a 2.5D volumetric texture in mid-range
- and a 2D texture in the distant

Now my questions are:

Is it posible to show a 2D texture as a level in the LOD object of three.js?

Can i merge lod objects in the distance? (Example: there are 10 meshes close to the camera, 2 group meshes in mid-range and one 2d texture in a distance far away)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: i would do it same way that @antont tells, it seems too specific for a general implementation in a 3D library. In your example the first 10meshes can be added in an object3D() and then to the lod. Then instead of re-using the meshes (which would not be useful for a lod) you create the 2 meshes for the middle-distance. Then the sprite. oh 26months later ^^

Answer (score 0):

I think that's possible in the sense that you can write logic to do all that.. so I bet not something that the simple lod system in Three.js gives now, but something you could do in your own lod system that write on / with Three.